# Signal a buffer was evaluated in an inferior process?

Tags: hooks, repl

I am aware that this is a bit of training wheels, and that I should just trust Emacs and my keystrokes. But I think part of it is just that there's a context switch involved and I have too long of habits.

I have two visible windows: `test.py` in one, the inferior process `*Python[/.../test.py]` in the other. The active is buffer for `test.py`. I evaluate buffer with `C-c C-c`.

I would like visual feedback (in either buffer) that the code was evaluated. A blink in `test.py` would probably be better than something in `*Python...]` since I'd like a cross language solution, not just something specific for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, I didn't see an obvious hook that is run.

However, the problem can still be solved using advice.  I would suggest using "after" advice on `python-shell-send-string`.  You could have it flash the current window (see whatever `visible-bell` does), or play a whooshing sound, or whatever you like.